# Mark x-ranges with background color

Tags: python, plotly

I am trying to use Plotly to visualize temperature in my home. I would like to mark the periods when the heating is on with a different background colour. So the final plot would look similar to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42955831/674976) or [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/24873702/674976), except that I want to do it in Plotly. Ideally the vertical range should be "infinite" so that the background colour doesn't depend on the displayed axes limits.

Is it possible?

[image]
[image]

Comment: The comment by max in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46843099/674976) might do the trick.

Comment: You could use 'shapes' with `rect` and use `yref: paper` to be indepedent of the axis scale.